# Como salvar o Retorno de um Webservice em disco?

Tags: c#

Estou precisando salvar no diretório um retorno de um `webservice`.

Como faço para gravar o valor dessa variável `ret` em um arquivo `xml`.

Retorno: XML do tipo Resultados.xsd

Tentei assim:

```
WSHP.XMLServer ws = new WSHP.XMLServer();
var xml = GerarXMLConsulta();
string login = "12000";
string senha = "4329";
var ret = ws.getResultado(login, senha, xml);
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Resultados));
FileStream arquivo = new FileStream("D:\\downloads\\Retorno.xml", FileMode.CreateNew);
ser.Serialize(arquivo, ret);
```

O `Visual Studio` retorno erro:

> Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'System.String' no tipo 'ModuloEtiquetas.Resultados'.

Comment: `var ret = ws.getResultado(login, senha, xml);` te retorna um objeto ou um xml?

Comment: Retorna um XML.

Comment: E você quer colocar o xml em um arquivo?

Comment: string retorno = ws.getResultado(login, senha, xml);
preciso salva a variável retorno em um xml.xml para outro sistema carregar esse arquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente sua pergunta, o retorno de `ws.getResultado(login, senha, xml);` já é um xml e você quer apenas salvar no diretório, então não há necessidade de serialização/descerialização no seu código.

Uma forma de fazer isso seria assim:

```
WSHP.XMLServer ws = new WSHP.XMLServer();
var xml = GerarXMLConsulta();
string login = "12000";
string senha = "4329";
var ret = ws.getResultado(login, senha, xml);

using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter("D:\\downloads\\Retorno.xml"))
{
    myWriter.Write(ret);
}
```

Comment: Maravilha, era isso que estava faltando.
Obrigado pela atenção.